# How to group by one column with single aggregate function but select multiple columns on oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to group by one column with aggregate function on single column while selecting multiple other column.This is easily achieved in MySQL by query below.

`SELECT sum(count),store,date,product FROM sales_log_bak where date > "2017-03-01" and date < "2017-04-05" group by date`

However,above query doesn't work on oracle Database.What will be equivalent query in oracle to achieve result as given by MySQL on above query?

Comment: Sadly this can be done in MySQL when not working in *strict-mode*. But it is ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174):

```
SELECT sum(sales_count) OVER (PARTITION BY sales_date), 
   store, sales_date, product 
FROM sales_log_bak 
where sales_date > DATE '2017-03-01' and sales_date < DATE '2017-04-05';
```

Note, `date` and `count` are reserved words in Oracle, you should not use them for column names.

Comment: could please kindly explain above query I cannot get my head on `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` , I have never came across those terminologies before.

Comment: @Flame - did you look at the documentation Wernfried linked to?